# Remove/hide product actions from category page via XML layout

Tags: magento-2.1

for Magento 2.1, does anyone know the block name for the product actions in the category page?

I'm trying to add an XML layout update to a specific category via Products > Categories > specific category > Design > Layout Update XML

I would like to remove the block that contains the add to cart button etc for all products in a certain category.

I have tried this but it doesn't work...

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Ideally I'd like to remove the whole div that has a class of '**product-item-inner**' or the div with class '**product-item-actions**'.

I could probably do it with CSS but I'd like to remove it if possible?

Thanks

Comment: you could override the `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` file